# Remove margin in a set of floating buttons

Tags: css

I have a container on my page with a designated width; this is so to be able to center all the buttons on the page.

I'm using `margin-right` on the buttons, but I'm not able to fill the container with the buttons so that they go edge-to-edge with the container, else they readjust and the grid becomes 3x4 instead of the desired 4x3.

So how do I get rid of the space (margin) at the end of the buttons? I can't use a `:last-child` selector obviously.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="months">
        <div class="month-button jan" data-month="January"></div>
        <div class="month-button feb" data-month="February"></div>
        <div class="month-button mar" data-month="March"></div>
        <div class="month-button apr" data-month="April"></div>

        <div class="month-button may" data-month="May"></div>
        <div class="month-button jun" data-month="June"></div>
        <div class="month-button jul" data-month="July"></div>
        <div class="month-button aug" data-month="August"></div>

        <div class="month-button sep" data-month="September"></div>
        <div class="month-button oct" data-month="October"></div>
        <div class="month-button nov" data-month="November"></div>
        <div class="month-button dec" data-month="December"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

#months {
    margin: 10px 5px 21px;

    float: left;
}

.month-button {
    width: 115px;
    height: 26px;

    background: url("/__resources/images/months.png");
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px 87px 0px 0px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: could you post the markup of your buttons?

Comment: Any reason for using all those classes? `class="month-button jan"` can't you just `#months > div`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) to zero the right margin for every 4th element:

```
.month-button:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

If you need to support old browsers then I suggest manually adding a class to every 4th element such as `zero-right-margin`:

```
.zero-right-margin {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Comment: :? now we can expect another question soon. What about the gap between `(3n)` and `(4n)` :)

Comment: This works as long as you don't need to cover ie8. Also OP need to readjust margins so the space between each button will fit nicely

Comment: @Huangism I think I might need it to work for IE8 as well (customer preference, unfortunately :/)

Comment: @silkfire it might or it need to? you need to find the requirements. If your buttons will always be laid out 4 in 1 row then you might as well make them into 3 rows

Comment: @Huangism I myself always run Chrome, but we have customers who use outdated browsers (IE *hint hint*) because their mother company is very strict about browser and version usage.

Comment: @silkfire the requirements for supported browsers should be clearly defined, if not then ask your superior. Ot to make things easier, as I mentioned before, make them into 3 rows (div container per row) if the layout i always like that

Comment: if you are using jQuery you may try with nth-child http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: I'll go for this solution. Thanks a ton, MrCode

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this.

```
#months{ /* This is the wrapper of your buttons */
    margin-right: -87px; /* Negative of buttons right margin */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck supporting IE8 as mentioned above, then you're best to seperate each row into it's own container.

IE8 doesn't support `:nth-child` or `:last-child`, but it does support `[:first-child][1]` pseudo classes. You can put your margins on the left instead of the right, and then use `[:first-child][2]` to remove the margins on the first occurrence only.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="months">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="month-button jan" data-month="January"></div>
            <div class="month-button feb" data-month="February"></div>
            <div class="month-button mar" data-month="March"></div>
            <div class="month-button apr" data-month="April"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="month-button may" data-month="May"></div>
            <div class="month-button jun" data-month="June"></div>
            <div class="month-button jul" data-month="July"></div>
            <div class="month-button aug" data-month="August"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="month-button sep" data-month="September"></div>
            <div class="month-button oct" data-month="October"></div>
            <div class="month-button nov" data-month="November"></div>
            <div class="month-button dec" data-month="December"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.month-button {
    width: 115px;
    height: 26px;

    background: url("/__resources/images/months.png");
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px 0px 0px 87px;
}
.month-button:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```